# Rendering mathematical equations from a string in LaTeX form in UWP

Tags: uwp, latex, mathjax

I have written a demo for recognizing math expressions. Now I have get the result in LaTeX form.

How can I use it to render mathematical equation?

Because I implement my demo in UWP (C#). So I hope for a solution which can also be used in UWP (C#).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not against using Xamarin.Forms, you can take a look at the [`CSharpMath` library](https://github.com/verybadcat/CSharpMath). It doesn't seem there is any purely C# solution available, but it might be possible to use Xamarin.Forms embedding to just embed the control in native UI if you don't want to use full Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: If it solves your question, pleaye consider marking it as answer so that it is closed :-). Happy coding!

Comment: I have found that there is a file named " CSharpMath.Forms.Example.UWP " .It seems that I can use this in my UWP. But  I don't know how to use this example.Could you please give me more detailed advice

Comment: I run the example.Then I click "Try" and click the "Load Latex" button.But an error raises as follows  " Access to the path 'C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\CSharpMath-master\CSharpMath.Forms.Example\CSharpMath.Forms.Example.UWP\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\SavedLaTeX.txt' is denied.”"  How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How are you specifying the path to the `SavedLaTeX.txt` file?

Comment: Try to create `SavedLaTeX.txt` file in the root of your UWP project and set its Build Action to `Content`

Comment: I have find another way in github   "https://github.com/totoroyyb/Render-Math-In-UWP-By-KaTex". By using this sample,I  implement what I want.

Comment: Thank you all the same! I think your solution can also solve my problem.But it's a little difficult for I am just start to learn UWP.

Comment: Hi, CSharpMath maintainer here. Sorry for your inconvenience. Normally, you can enter LaTeX code in the textbox above the "Load/Save LaTeX" buttons and everything will be shown below. Those buttons are experimental in hopes of a cross-platform solution to a file picker dialog in Xamarin.Forms, but I couldn't find any. I forgot to remove those buttons! :(

Comment: @Happypig375 The library looks great :-) . It would be awesome if it offered "native" Xamarin version for Android and UWP as well (as it seems iOS is there and Forms is already implemented, it should be possible)

Comment: I'm thinking of Forms Embedding. Maybe I can add them in the README?

Comment: Yes, Form Embedding is good, but it is not 100 % solution currently (AFAIK), because it enables embedding a whole page, not just control for example, which would be great here.

Comment: Thanks. Added to the TODO list.